# Select last hour of data in Access query

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to pull data for the last hour or two from a table but the data field and time field are separate fields.

The field "date_stamp" is a Date/Time field but the "time_stamp" field is short text. I cannot find a way to combine these to grab my data for the last hour.

Thank you!

Comment: Post some sample data here as text table and then show your expected output.

Comment: I want pull all data from a table for the last hour. I don't see why you need a sample.

Comment: SO is not free code writing service. You must include your own attempts, minimal reproduceable sample. We are unable to help you until you help us.

Comment: I just want to do:
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_stamp = date() AND time_stamp = DateAdd("h",-1,Now())

I always get nothing back because time_stamp is a text field and not a proper date field in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You must convert your text time to true time.
Then you can filter like this:

```sql
Select * 
From table 
Where 
    date_stamp + TimeValue(time_stamp) Between DateAdd("h", -1, Now()) And Now()
```